# What does 按 mean in 打印机好像坏了，我按半天了，一直没反应?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is from a HSK5 exam listening section:

> 男：打印机好像坏了，**我按半天了**，一直没反应。
> 女：昨天刚修的，居然又坏了?真耽误事儿，我看看。
> 问：女的对什么感到奇怪?

I'm not sure what 按 is doing in this sentence.  From the context, it seems to mean something like "attempted to operate".

> 按 (àn​)
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%8C%89): to press / to push / to leave aside or shelve / to control / to restrain / to keep one's hand on / to check or refer to / according to / in the light of / (of an editor or author) to make a comment

Perhaps "to control" is the appropriate meaning here.  I'm not sure.

**Question**: What does 按 mean in 打印机好像坏了，我按半天了，一直没反应?

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/?sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E6%89%93%E5%8D%B0%E6%9C%BA%E5%A5%BD%E5%83%8F%E5%9D%8F%E4%BA%86%EF%BC%8C%E6%88%91%E6%8C%89%E5%8D%8A%E5%A4%A9%E4%BA%86%EF%BC%8C%E4%B8%80%E7%9B%B4%E6%B2%A1%E5%8F%8D%E5%BA%94%E3%80%82&op=translate) translates the first part to the following, which is not particularly helpful:

> The printer seems to be broken. I have pressed it for a long time, but there is no response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can treated it as an abbreviation of :

> 打印机好像坏了，我按半天了(按钮)，一直没反应。

Or in English,

> .... I have pressed (the buttons on) it for a long time, ....